# docker-compose args from shell

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I want to build via the `docker-compose` an image that uses my private key for cloning private `git` repos.

More or less the compose becomes as follows:

```
   myservice:
     build:
      context: .
      args:
        RSA:  ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

The above does not work, neither the following:

```
   myservice:
     build:
      context: .
      args:
        RSA: $(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa)
```

The docker build command works just fine however in the form of

```
docker build --build-args RSA=$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa) -t myservice:latest
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the same syntax with docker-compose build:

```
docker-compose build --build-arg RSA="$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa)"
```

Unfortunately, you can't use the build-args option with compose up or start... So you will need to build and then run using the `--no-build` option

Comment: Thanks. In the mean time I resorted to sth like: `export RSA=$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa) && docker-compose up --build` since env vars seem to work.

Comment: I think it's `--build-arg` (without 's'). Also, for docker-compose version =< 1.19.0, you need to specify a service (this should change in the future). It mean that you can't build all the project in one shot. A better solution is to pass the key as an environnement variable that will be use as the value of the build args in the docker-compose file. See my answer for more info.

Comment: It should be `docker-compose build --build-arg  RSA="$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa)"`

Answer (score 8):

One way to do it that will work when building all the services and also with `up` is to pass the SSH key data as an environnement variable like this:

```
env RSA=$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa) docker-compose build
```

And then you set the build args in the compose file like this:

```
myservice:
 build:
  context: .
  args:
    RSA: |-
      ${RSA}
```

Comment: Thank you.
But what does this symbol mean: "| -"?
And could you tell me how to set a default value in compose file?
For example: args: RSA: ${RSA} or "some default value if empty"

Comment: The "|" in YAML start a multi-line string that preserve newlines and the "-" indicate that all newlines at the end of the string should be striped. Check https://yaml-multiline.info/. For the default value, the syntax is `${VARIABLE:-default}` (for 2.1 compose file format). Check https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution

Answer (score -5):

add `ARGS` in your Dockerfile like

`ARGS RSA`

For it to be read upon build

Comment: I have added `ARG` that's why the `docker build` command works